# How can I get two platforms to exchange data by leveraging their REST APIs

Tags: rest, web-services, client-server

I use two independent eCommerce platforms that don't officially support communication with one another, however, both have exposed REST API for managing products, orders, etc.

My question is: how can I leverage their APIs to allow the two platforms to exchange data?
Neither platform offers a workspace to code API calls and execute on retrieved records, so I don't understand how this scenario fits in the client server model.

Would this require a third node to be set up to act as the client with each of the eCommerce platforms acting as servers?
If so, then I surmise that this client would need to, for example, perform a GET request from Platform A, store the retrieved records in a database, then perform a POST to create the records in Platform B.

If my above understanding is correct, can anyone please advise on a platform/service with which this functionality can be built and managed? Is [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) what I'm looking for?

I'm still new to web API development, so please excuse my ignorance.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out on my own. Indeed, Postman is the service I was looking for.

I'm using a combination of Collections, pre-request scripts, test scripts, the different variable types, and the Collection Runner to automate the exchange between the two platforms.

The process essentially involves creating Collections for each type of exchange. They each mainly perform a GET request from platform A with a test script (script that runs immediately after the request) that assigns the retrieved JSON data to a variable. The next request uses a pre-request script to access the variable and format the data according to the schema required for platform B. Then a POST request sends the reformatted data to Platform B. There is no need to store the transient retrieved records in a database, as I had speculated in my OP. The Collection Runner is the feature that allows you to schedule the API calls to run automatically and in the required sequence.

My first collection was up and running fairly quickly, but it took a little while longer to complete some of the more complicated ones. I highly recommend Postman. Their basic plan is free and allows up to 1000 API calls per month.

I hope this info can help others seeking a similar solution.